Failed to download file: 404 - {"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"User not found","innerError":
I was trying to download a specific file which is located in OneDrive using Graph API. I have created an Azure Application to download and upload the file. Because it's my first time working with this API, I am not sure why I am getting response message with User not Found. I have the Tenant ID, Client Secret and Client ID all ready.
Code:
import time

import requests
import os

# Azure AD credentials
client_id = '7827d4d5-e06e-4dc3-b4df-92fde865d9fd'
client_secret = 'LqE8Q~yQ2QWmyPL62pZE~pwIRukrq.nUefaRic7g'
tenant_id = 'a38bf430-8119-4d00-b314-1bf3d9eadd6b'

def get_access_token():
    # Get an access token using client credentials flow
    token_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    payload = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    }
    response = requests.post(token_url, data=payload).json()
    return response.get('access_token')

def download_file_from_onedrive(file_path_onedrive, local_file_path):
    access_token = get_access_token()
    if access_token:
        # Construct the URL for the file using the user ID
        user_id = 'your-user-id'  # Replace 'your-user-id' with the actual user ID or principal name
        file_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/drive/root:{file_path_onedrive}:/content'

        # Download the file from OneDrive
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
        }
        response = requests.get(file_url, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Save the file locally
            with open(local_file_path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.content)
            print(f"File downloaded successfully to {local_file_path}")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to download file: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
    else:
        print("Failed to obtain access token")

def upload_file_to_onedrive(local_file_path, file_path_onedrive):
    access_token = get_access_token()
    print()
    if access_token:
        # Construct the URL for the upload
        upload_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:{file_path_onedrive}:/content'

        # Upload the file to OneDrive
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
        }
        with open(local_file_path, 'rb') as f:
            response = requests.put(upload_url, headers=headers, data=f)

        if response.status_code == 201:
            print(f"File uploaded successfully to OneDrive: {file_path_onedrive}")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to upload file: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
    else:
        print("Failed to obtain access token")

# Example usage:
onedrive_file_path = '/Details.xlsx'
local_file_path = 'Details.xlsx'

# Download file from OneDrive to local directory
download_file_from_onedrive(onedrive_file_path, local_file_path)
time.sleep(10)
# Upload file from local directory to OneDrive
# upload_file_to_onedrive(local_file_path, onedrive_file_path)

Permissions:
enter image description here
Error:
Failed to download file: 404 - {"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"User not        found","innerError":{"date":"2024-04-17T21:26:07","request-id":"56a4e23e-3e58-406a-8981-       6e01230356eb","client-request-id":"56a4e23e-3e58-406a-8981-6e01230356eb"}}}

Permissions:
(https://i.sstatic.net/aTjmG.png)
Is there a way I can download the file and solve this issue?

My guess is that user_id is a userid that doesn't exist.

user_id = 'your-user-id' Did you do as the comment says, and replace this string with the actual userid?

I appreciate your insight, I have been stuck in this code and it was very silly of me for not noticing user_id in the code

You need to pass a value to user_id.
In your example your download_file_from_onedrive function has user_id set to "your-user-id". Hence, the API is producing the user not found response.

you haven't defined it inside the function Yes they did.  But in the code it's defined as user_id = 'your-user-id'.  It's unclear if they used this literal value, or if this is just obfuscation.

@JohnGordon My bad. I missed it. Thanks :)
